# how to fix the error " invalid the type error" in the postgresql function .the code is pasted .kindly fix the code

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION msaccess_utilities.choose_ (p_index bigint, p_element_1 text,
 p_element_2 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_3 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_4 text DEFAULT NULL,
 p_element_5 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_6 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_7 text DEFAULT NULL,
 p_element_8 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_9 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_10 text DEFAULT NULL,
 p_element_11 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_12 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_13 text DEFAULT NULL,
 p_element_14 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_15 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_16 text DEFAULT NULL,
 p_element_17 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_18 text DEFAULT NULL, p_element_19 text DEFAULT NULL,
 p_element_20 text DEFAULT NULL) RETURNS varchar AS $body$
DECLARE

    TYPE StringCollType IS TABLE OF varchar(4000);
    v_coll StringCollType;

BEGIN
v_coll := new StringCollType();

IF p_element_1 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_1;
END IF;

IF p_element_2 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_2;
END IF;

IF p_element_3 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_3;
END IF;

IF p_element_4 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_4;
END IF;

IF p_element_5 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_5;
END IF;

IF p_element_6 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_6;
END IF;

IF p_element_7 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_7;
END IF;

IF p_element_8 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_8;
END IF;

IF p_element_9 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_9;
END IF;

IF p_element_10 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_10;
END IF;

IF p_element_11 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_11;
END IF;

IF p_element_12 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_12;
END IF;

IF p_element_13 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_13;
END IF;

IF p_element_14 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_14;
END IF;

IF p_element_15 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_15;
END IF;

IF p_element_16 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_16;
END IF;

IF p_element_17 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_17;
END IF;

IF p_element_18 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_18;
END IF;

IF p_element_19 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_19;
END IF;

IF p_element_20 IS NOT NULL THEN
  v_coll.EXTEND(1);
  v_coll(v_coll.LAST) := p_element_20;
END IF;

IF p_index < 1 OR p_index > v_coll.COUNT THEN
  RETURN NULL;
END IF;

RETURN v_coll(ROUND(p_index));
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION '%', DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK USING ERRCODE = '45000';
END;

$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
 STABLE;
```

Comment: `TYPE StringCollType IS TABLE OF varchar(4000);` is invalid in Postgres. Where in the manual did you find that? Postgres also has no `dbms_utilty` package.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing Oracle and Postgres code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the code, you are trying to convert a list of parameters into an array, in order to pick one of those parameters specified by the first parameter as the return value.

This can be done a **lot** easier with Postgres:

```
create function choose_(p_index int, p_element variadic text[] )
  returns text
as
$$
  select p_element[p_index];
$$
language sql;
```

```
postgres=> select choose_(2, 'one', 'two', 'three');
 choose_
---------
 two
(1 row)


postgres=> select choose_(5, 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
 choose_
---------

(1 row)


postgres=> select choose_(5, 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six');
 choose_
---------
 five
(1 row)
```

[Oracle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=98248ee1c5dc37c6d28bdd086ea2158e)

[Postgres demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ae76dc16256bc96d94d28466b16863d3)